# Setting up Application Insights on a console app

Tags: log4net, azure-application-insights

I've got Log4Net running on a console app, and would like the log events to go to Application Insights.

I'm not able to add AI by right-clicking on my project-it does not appear as an option.

I've installed the AI SDK through NuGet, and am able to create telemetry clients, but don't know where to add the instrumentation key.

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-windows-desktop) tutorial says:

*Set the instrumentation key either in your code:*

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = " your key ";
```

*or in ApplicationInsights.config (if you installed one of the standard telemetry packages):*

```
<InstrumentationKey>your key</InstrumentationKey>
```

I don't have an ApplicationInsights.config file, since I was not able to add AI to the project. Would it work if I just added the key as I instantiate the telemetry client, like this?

```
var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient { InstrumentationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["applicationInsights"] };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You last suggestion will probably work. You can also do it like this:

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["applicationInsights"];
```

Comment: Somewhere at the start of your program, in the main. Or in an init method.